# create recursive power of 2 '*' in python

Tags: python

In pyschools, I am stuck in the power of 2 recursive function

```
    >>> createStars(0)      # 2 to power of 0 = 1
    '*'
    >>> createStars(1)      # 2 to power of 1 = 2
    '**'
    >>> createStars(2)      # 2 to power of 2 = 4
    '****'
    >>> createStars(3)      # 2 to power of 3 = 8
    '********'
```

What I am trying to do is as following:

```
def createStars(x):
    if x == 0:
        return '*'
    else:
        return '*' * x + createStars(x-1)
```

However, this seems to be a summation of 'x' not power of 2.
Meaning, this will break when the x is higher than 2

I know how to do the power of 2 recursively but no idea where to change to make createStars() work.

```
def power(x, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return x * power(x, n-1)
```

PS. I know it is easy to use non-recursive method to solve it. 
    But would like to seek advice how to do it in recursive way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def createStars(x):
    if x == 0:
        return '*'
    else:
        return createStars(x-1) * 2
```

(Each step back in the recursion doubles the number of stars in the output string).

Comment: Yes! Thanks, xnx. I was instructed to use '+' but totally forgot to use multiplication..

Answer (score 1):

You're very close!

I would suggest comparing the two pieces of code you gave us. (I'm going to rename it a bit to make the analogy more clear):

```
def createStars(n):
    if n == 0:
        return '*'
    else:
        return '*' * n + createStars(n-1) 


def power(x, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return x * power(x, n-1)
```

They have *almost* exactly the same structure. In particular, the last line of each has a slightly different structure.

In the (working) power, you multiply the result for `n-1` by `x`. So, when computing the power(2, 6), you increase power(2, 5) by 2. (i.e. you *multiply* 32 by 2 to get 64).

In the (not working) createStars, you're not multiplying the result for the `n-1` case by anything; you're just adding stuff to the start of it. What if you change it to make the structures match?

Also, you should check what the result is for `createStars(1)`.